# Array with two objects and string how to remove Quotes

Tags: object, concatenation, quotes

I had to .concat two objects and a string, the string didn't have surrounding quotes and now it does, I have tried .replace in every different way, please, is there a way to remove the quotes surrounding a string inside array with other objects
var keywrdrtrn = `{city_name:'${city_name}'}`
var obj =v[0].concat(v[1]).concat(keywrdrtrn);
}
obj [
{
city_name: 'Cincinnati',
},
{
city_name: 'Mumbai',
},
"{city_name:'',state: ''}"
]

I have removed other index/objects for space but the format is same. I just cannot figure out how to concat the setup without quotes being added or figuring out how to remove quotes after concat

I tried .replace and I tried to convert string to object prior to concat

Comment: in what programming language?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first query on here, I should have included, nodeJS is the language and we use angularjs